# Graph in blog not suited for dark mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog, dark-mode

In this new [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/03/how-stack-overflow-hires-engineers/?cb=1) entry the graph is hard to read.

[image]

Comment: This could've been avoided, and made more accessible, if HTML/CSS/JS was preferred over images

Comment: @Zoe It’s an SVG, so they might still be able to adjust the colors for dark and light mode. (It looks SVGs can also be accessible but I don’t have experience in that area.)

Comment: So much this. Despite knowing better I hope this won't get ignored this time..

Comment: This looks to be fixed in the meanwhile.

Comment: @m0sa would you care to add a [tag:status-completed] please?